# I'm having trouble while using metaweather/location api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I'm getting the following error

```
crossorigin.me/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 522 ()
AJAX calls with FETCH and PROMISES.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
AJAX calls with FETCH and PROMISES.html:18 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I've tried to solve it through crossorigin.me, but it didn't work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Making AJAX calls with FETCH and PROMISES</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        fetch('https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/')

        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm expecting for the promise response

Comment: 522 is a CloudFlare's response saying the target server (`crossorigin.me` or `metaweather.com`) is not reachable.

Comment: Is there any possible solution to that?

Comment: No, there's nothing you can do, except to drop them a line and ask

Comment: is there any alternate api for this?

Comment: Does it work without `crossorigin.me`, since this is the one that is having problems?

Comment: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/ with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details. 
Now i'm getting this error

Comment: You need an intermediate proxy server that would deal with CORS, a 3rd party or your own.

Comment: It worked, i used the following proxy: 
https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=<url_to_http_resource>
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: anytime...... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same api.

I found out that the website crossorigin.me unfortunately is no longer maintained and the domain is now actually up for sale.

The good news is there are other ways to get this done. Moreover, is worth noticing that after some searching on the internet, the metaweather api itself has some hard time to get fetched with ajax. So many users struggle with it. So you might consider using a different api. See this github code for your reference I tried it only it needs a little tweaking as it is not fully functional: [metaweather api gist](https://gist.github.com/liviupreda/89cd264bf26f2ad1fefd80f3c2e17ac8)